# Using os.stats on a google bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to use the python `os.stat()` on a google cloud storage bucket, such as:

```py
video = "gs://cloudmleap/video/next/JaneGoodall.mp4"
stat = os.stat(video)
print(stat)
```

I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://cloudmleap/video/next/JaneGoodall.mp4'
```

Thanks

Comment: So... what's the error?

Comment: Oops sorry about that! FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://cloudmleap/video/next/JaneGoodall.mp4'

Comment: `os.stat` is a filesystem operation. It doesn't make sense to use it here.

Comment: Understood, but I still need the metadata from the files. Any suggestions on how to get it?

Comment: See: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#code-samples

Comment: Jinks! Thanks, Daz! I just found it after googling the write question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this does it:

`from google.cloud import storage`

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-set-object-metadata-python